# Add EDITTEXT as a submenu option android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, submenu

I defined my sub-menu in the XML menu file ( it works ). My intent is to add an EDIT option and a View option. I would like to use a EDITTEXT for the EDIT option. How can I link an EDIT text to my submenu? Thank you in advance.

Please bear with me if I'm asking very simple questions :).

Comment: By sub menu do you mean the menu that pops up when the user presses the menu key? This is also the same thing as the overflow menu (three dots) on newer phones without a menu key.

Comment: Actually something like this: I have a regular menu which has 2 tabs ( About and Settings ). In the SETTINGS menu (defined in the menu.XML) 2 more SUBMENUS View and EDIT ( obviously they don't do anything right now). I would like EDIT to be linked to an EDITTEXT or something that can be editable. Thank you !

Comment: Ah, I see. Is the edit option in a ListView or is it a Button? You might want to post the layout xml so we can see what you're trying to do. On that note, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"android:titleCondensed="Settings">
        <menu>
      <item android:id="@+id/menu_view" android:title="View</item>
         <item android:id="@+id/menu_edit" android:title="Edit"></item>
     </menu>
    </item>      
    <item android:id="@+id/about_us"
        android:title="@string/about_us"android:titleCondensed="About US"
     android:icon="@drawable/icon"
     android:menuCategory="secondary"/>    
</menu>

Comment: I do have an EditText button on the main layout that does what it's suppose to. I want to move it from the main layout in to the sub-menu, to be part of the SETTINGS. Actually what would be the best approach? Thanks :)

Comment: Please, use the edit button. Code in comments is not easy on the eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend having an EditText *inside* the menu, this is too much work and you deviate from the default functionality of the Android menu. What I would do instead is make the "Edit" option launch either a separate `Activity` or show a `Dialog` with an `EditText`. Of the two, I would recommend showing a Dialog using a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) , it's the simplest you can do. [This](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) Android Dev Blog post gives a tutorial. Basically, you will have to make your own layout for the DialogFragment (you will probably want an `EditText` and `Button`, then when the `DialogFragment` is created, you inflate the layout and attach an `[onClickListener][3]` to your `Button` that saves the text and dismisses the `DialogFragment`.

These next code blocks just show how your menu should be implemented. This code inflates your menu xml - it is needed.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

This code handles your logic. Note the `case R.id.menu_edit:` That's where you have to handle the logic for the user pressing "Edit" from the menu.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_view:
                //do stuff here
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_edit:
                //make a Dialog or show an Activity
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

Lastly, don't be afraid to try stuff out, it doesn't bite.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I needed, a good advice guiding me in the right direction. I will play this weekend until it will work the way I wanted. Thanks again for your time :)